# Java make a copy of a reader

Tags: java, streamreader, datareader

I have a BufferedReader looping through a file. When I hit a specific case, I would like to continue looping using a different instance of the reader but starting at this point.

Any ideas for a recommended solution? Create a separate reader, use the mark function, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While waiting for your answer to my comment, I'm stuck with making assumptions.

If it's the linewise input you value, you may be as pleasantly surprised as I was to discover that `RandomAccessFile` now (since 1.4 or 1.5) supports the `readLine` method. Of course RandomAccessFile gives you fine-grained control over position.

If you want buffered IO, you may consider wrapping a reader around a `CharacterBuffer` or maybe a `ByteBuffer` wrapped around a file mapped using the `nio` API. This gives you the ability to treat a file as memory, with fine control of the read pointer. And because the data is all in memory, buffering is included free of charge.

Comment: Yes, that was it, the `RandomAccessFile` :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `BufferedReader`'s [`mark`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark%28int%29) method?  Used in conjunction with [`reset`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#reset%28%29) it might meet your needs.

Comment: mark is tough to use because i don't know the size of the incoming buffer (or how far through the buffer i am)

Comment: Why are you using BufferedReader? Is it for performance or to use the readLine() method?

Comment: (as opposed to a plain FileReader, I mean)

Answer (score 0):

If you keep track of how many characters you've read so far, you can create a new BufferedReader and use [skip](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#skip%28long%29).

As Noel has pointed out, you would need to avoid using `BufferedReader.readLine()`, since `readLine()` will discard newlines and make your character count inaccurate.  You probably shouldn't count on readLine() never getting called if anyone else will ever have to maintain your code.

If you do decide to use `skip`, you should write your own buffered Reader which will give you an offset counting the newlines.

Comment: Workable if use of BufferedReader.readLine() is avoided, which discards newline data, or newline utilization is standardized.